# Supabase PostgreSQL query error: Failed to run sql query: column __ does not exist

Tags: postgresql, supabase

Every solution I see has to do with people having case sensitive column names.

The query `select * from users` works, but when I say `select * from users where username=maxspiri`, I get error column maxspiri doesn't exist. Here is my table:

[image]

Comment: [String constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) in the Postgres manual

Comment: This is because maxspiri identify as a column by psql. Change it to 'maxspiri'

Answer (score 2):

Since `maxspiri` is a string, you need to wrap it in single quotes.

```sql
select * from users where username='maxspiri'
```

Comment: This answer is correct and should be marked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking into this:

Column names in Supabase should be wrapped in double quotes, but strings (values) should be wrapped in single quotes:

```
SELECT "id" from "table" WHERE "name" = 'some string value'
```

If your table, or column, has an uppercase in it (e.g. tableName) and if you don't wrap it in double quotes (e.g. "tableName") Supabase will convert it to lower case (e.g. tablename) and it won't find such table/column.